# Processing comments on YouTube's New Look

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I'm creating a userscript for Greasemonkey, for displaying additional content near comments in YouTube. I want it to support both Classic mode and New Look (based on Polymer, can be activated at https://www.youtube.com/new ), and I've already implemented most of functionality I wanted.

But a major problem I've recently found is related to apparently complicated YouTube mechanics involving the following processes:

- (1) Loading first batch of comments from cache.
- (2) Loading any further batches of comments from cache.

To do stuff with each comment, I use `waitForKeyElements` to catch them.
This works well when I'm not leaving the current page. But, when I open a different video on the same page, or when I open any other YouTube page and then press Back, stuff breaks.

After navigating, comments that should be processed by the script appear already processed. Of course, that's how YouTube's no-reload design works.

At some point I was able to make the script recognize navigation event `yt-navigate-finish` - this solved the problem (1). But another problem (2) remains - new batches of comments appear cached and getting re-inserted, and re-filled. This is where I couldn't find the solution.

**To demonstrate the problem,** I've created a small Greasemonkey script (MCVE):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       TEST2
// @include    https://*youtube.com/*
// @require    https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js
// @grant      none
// @run-at     document-start
// ==/UserScript==

waitForKeyElements('#main .style-scope ytd-comment-renderer', ParseItemTest);

function ParseItemTest(jNode) {
    var aNode = $(jNode).find("#author-text")[0];
    var newspan = document.createElement('span');
    newspan.innerHTML = ' <font color="red">===</font> ' + $(aNode).find("span.style-scope.ytd-comment-renderer").html();
  $(aNode).append(newspan);
}

function waitForKeyElements(selectorTxt, actionFunction, bWaitOnce, iframeSelector) {
    var targetNodes, btargetsFound;
    if (typeof iframeSelector == "undefined") targetNodes = $(selectorTxt);
    else targetNodes = $(iframeSelector).contents().find(selectorTxt);
    if (targetNodes && targetNodes.length > 0) {
        btargetsFound = true;
        targetNodes.each(function() {
            var jThis = $(this);
            var alreadyFound = jThis.data('alreadyFound') || false;
            if (!alreadyFound) {
                var cancelFound = actionFunction(jThis);
                if (cancelFound) btargetsFound = false;
                else jThis.data('alreadyFound', true);
            }
        });
    } else {
        btargetsFound = false;
    }
    var controlObj = waitForKeyElements.controlObj || {};
    var controlKey = selectorTxt.replace(/[^\w]/g, "_");
    var timeControl = controlObj[controlKey];
    if (btargetsFound && bWaitOnce && timeControl) {
        clearInterval(timeControl);
        delete controlObj[controlKey];
    } else {
        if (!timeControl) {
            timeControl = setInterval(function() {
                waitForKeyElements(selectorTxt, actionFunction, bWaitOnce, iframeSelector);
            }, 300);
            controlObj[controlKey] = timeControl;
        }
    }
    waitForKeyElements.controlObj = controlObj;
}
```

**With this script active,** enable YouTube's New Look and go to any video with comments. Let them load, note how each comment gets a username added, e.g.

> Alice === Alice
>
> John === John
>
> Grace === Grace

After you open any other page and press Back, here is what you'll see:

> Alice === Grace
>
> John === John
>
> Grace === Alice

And after you go to another video page and check the comments, you'll see:

> Jane === Grace
>
> Dorothy === John
>
> Brad === Alice

I hope it's enough to explain the problem. I just need to catch a moment where YouTube fills the existing comment elements with new data, to parse them again with that new data.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the effort, Brock Adams.

However I've already came up with somewhat similar solution. In case this helps anyone, here is how it works:

- I set up `MutationObserver`, to watch for changes in `<paper-spinner-lite>` objects.
- For each found change, I check if the child `div#main.style-scope.ytd-comment-renderer` has `cooldown` class. The logic which works for me:
- If yes, I re-check and re-process each comment.
- If no, I remove each comment element. They'll get properly re-initialized by YouTube.

(I may post the actual code later when I have the time.)

Comment: Remember [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Thank you.